# c# Filter int for specific parameter

Tags: c#, numbers

Is there any more "elegant" way to filter a number input for specific parameters?

Like here, I need to say different things if you're to high, to low or of the limits.

Would appreciate if you explain what you suggest. I'm like 2 weeks into programming.

```
      //VARIABLES
      int userNumber;//uN
      int searchedNumber;//sN

      //NUMBER WE'RE LOOKING FOR
      searchedNumber = 87;

      //TASK FOR "CUSTOMER"
      Console.WriteLine("Type in a number between 1-100!");

      //DO-WHILE, because it hast to run one either way
      do 
      {
        //READING OUT CONSOLE
        string userNumberString = Console.ReadLine();

        //CONVERTING STRING TO INT
        userNumber = int.Parse(userNumberString);

        //uN > THAN sN BUT <= 100
        if (userNumber > searchedNumber && userNumber <= 100)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("To High! /n Try again.");
        }
        //uN < THAN sN BUT >= 1
        else if (userNumber < searchedNumber && userNumber >= 1)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("To Low!  /n Try again.");
        }
        //uN >= 101 AND uN <= 0
        else if (userNumber >= 101 || userNumber <= 0)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Between 1 and 100, Dummy!");
        }
        else
        {
        //IF NOTHING IS TRUE uN=sN
          Console.WriteLine("JACKPOT!");
        }
      //LOOPING CONDITION
      } while (userNumber != searchedNumber);
```

If this q is already answered somewhere, i'm sorry. English is not my native language and i struggled to even find the right search term.

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: there is none. that code is just really error-prone. what i wan't to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *extracting methods*, please, do not cram everything into huge single routine:

```
  public static int ReadInteger(string title) {
    if (!string.ISNullOrWhiteSpace(title))  
      Console.WriteLine(title);

    while (true) {
      if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
        return result;

      Console.WriteLine("This is not a valid integer! Try again.");
    }
  }

  public static string FeedBack(int user, int actual) {
    if (user < 0 || user > 100)
      return "Between 1 and 100, Dummy!"
    else if (user < actual)
      return "Too Low!  /n Try again.";
    else if (user > actual)
      return "Too High! /n Try again.";
    else
      return "JACKPOT!"
  }
```

Then use these methods in a tiny loop:

```
  int userNumber = 0;
  int searchedNumber = 87;

  do {
    userNumber = ReadInteger("Type in a number between 1-100!");

    Console.WriteLine(FeedBack(userNumber, actual)); 
  }     
  while (userNumber != searchedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get rid of all the `else` statements is to move the code to a method and return from the method as soon as you know what the response should be.
Something like this

```
public string EvaluateNumber(int userNumber, int searchedNumber)
{
    if (searchedNumber <= 0 || searchedNumber >= 101)
        return "Between 1 and 100, Dummy!";
    if (searchedNumber < userNumber)
        return "Too low! /n Try again.";
    if (searchedNumber > userNumber)
        return "Too high! /n Try again.";
    return "JACKPOT!"; // If we get to here, the numbers are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can get little bit cleaner by rearramging conditions - `if` will get a lot simplier :) Also, if you have one line under if, you can omit curly braces, see below code. I also included some comments, which I hope, wil be useful:

```
do 
{
  //READING OUT CONSOLE
  string userNumberString = Console.ReadLine();

  //CONVERTING STRING TO INT
  // here you need to be careful, what if user types "a"?
  // I suggest reading about int.TryParse :)
  userNumber = int.Parse(userNumberString);

  //uN >= 101 AND uN <= 0
  if (userNumber >= 101 || userNumber <= 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Between 1 and 100, Dummy!");
  // now we are sure we are in the range
  if (userNumber > searchedNumber)
    Console.WriteLine("To High! /n Try again.");
  else if (userNumber < searchedNumber)
    Console.WriteLine("To Low!  /n Try again.");
  else
    //IF NOTHING IS TRUE uN=sN
    Console.WriteLine("JACKPOT!");
//LOOPING CONDITION
} while (userNumber != searchedNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of a cleaner code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    //VARIABLES
    int userNumber;//uN
    int searchedNumber = 87;
    int min = 1;
    int max = 100;

    //TASK FOR "CUSTOMER"
    Console.WriteLine($"Type in a number between {min}-{max}!");

    //DO-WHILE, because it hast to run one either way
    do
    {
        //READING OUT CONSOLE
        string userNumberString = Console.ReadLine();
        //CONVERTING STRING TO INT
        if (int.TryParse(userNumberString, out userNumber))
        {
            if (userNumber >= min && userNumber <= max)
            {
                if (userNumber == searchedNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("JACKPOT!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("To " + (userNumber < searchedNumber ? "Low" : "High") + "! Try again.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Between {min} and {max}, Dummy!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"One integer number, Dummy!");
        }

    } while (userNumber != searchedNumber);
}
```

> The `TryParse` it's very important

Comment: This style (*arrow head antipattern*, see https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/) often makes code *difficult to mainatin*. Imagine, that we want to add `if (Math.Abs(userNumber, searchedNumber) < 3) Console.WriteLine("Very near!");` and `if (Math.Abs(userNumber, searchedNumber) > 50) Console.WriteLine("Far away!");`  conditions; it's not very clear *where* should we place them

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Bychenko,I will improve on that